# integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{ x^3 \cos(x)}{x^6 + 1} \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

How does someone solve

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ x^3  \cos(x)}{x^6 + 1} \mathrm{d}x $$

Is this analytically possible? I have no idea and I think if it is, it must be probably be solved via the Fourier/residue theorem or something like that.

Comment: It's definitely possible, according to wolframalpha the answer is 0.118802...I'm not sure how to evaluate it though by hand

Comment: It can be written in terms of cosine-integral function and sine-integral function. The reason is rather simple: we can compute $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x - z} \, dx$$ for $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$ in terms of those special functions, and your integral can be written as a linear combination of integrals of this form. I strongly suspect that it cannot be reduced to a simpler closed form. On the other hand, if $0 \leq m < n$ are even integers then $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^m \cos x}{x^n + 1} \, dx $$ can be written in elementary form by residue computation.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much, I will try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sangchul Lee commented, we could use partial fractions to get 
$$\frac{ x^3  \cos(x)}{x^6 + 1}=\sum_{i=1}^6 a_i \frac{\cos(x)}{x-b_i}$$ and then use $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x-c}\,dx=-\text{Ci}(-c) \cos (c)-\text{Si}(c) \sin (c)-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sin (c)$$ (provided that $\Im(c)\neq 0\lor \Re(c)\leq 0$). This would be quite tedious but doable.

To my surprise, a CAS gave 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ x^3  \cos(x)}{x^6 + 1} \,dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{3}} G_{1,7}^{4,1}\left(\frac{1}{46656}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{3} \\
 0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6}
\end{array}
\right)$$ where appears the Meijer G function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html)).

Its numerical value is $0.118802427933651$.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is CAS? (Computer arithmetic/algebraic Simulation?)

Comment: @WaldoRozir.**Computer Algebra System**. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system

Answer (score 0):

It may be solved by calculus of residue, i.e. considering a suitable line integral over a simple closed curve on $\mathbb{C}$. For example, the famous Dirichlet (improper ) integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ is computed by this trick.

Comment: Not an answer until you show *which* curve does the job.

Comment: And $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ has a nice closed form, but the same does not apply to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x+1}\,dx$, for instance. By partial fraction decomposition the integral considered by the OP depends on values of $\text{Si}$ and $\text{Ci}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the integrand is an odd function. If $x^3$ is changed to $x^4$, then we can consider integration from $(-R,0)$ to $(R,0)$ along the $x$-axis, then along the upper semi-circle with radius $R$ and center $O$ and let then let $R\rightarrow\infty$.